# mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysql-real-escape-string

I am using Codeigniter.i want to use string in `$_POST` value from search form which may contain special characters such as apostrophe('),(;) etc .How can my mysql query ignore these characters so that i could select from/save my `$_POST['search']` values into the database?

Whenever i use the mysql_real_escape_string() function.it give me: 
`mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied error.`

My code looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE  
product_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search'])."'";

$this->db->query($query);
```

How can deal with this problem in codeigniter? Thanks

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string()

Needs one at least mysql connection open, or a connection handle as a second parameter to work, because it depends on some server values to know how to escape your string. As Codeigniter DB library is probably using mysqli library (instead of mysql).

Answer (score 1):

Never use user input directly into your queries. Read more about "sql injection" and "xss" .
For codeIgnitor,do this :

1. Do not use $_POST, use the [input class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) instead.  `$this->input->post`
2. Use [query binding](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide//database/queries.html) , mysql_real_escape_string is not needed.
   eg.

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";

   $this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it would be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name=?";
$this->db->query($query, array($this->input->post('search'));
```

Have a look at the docs here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

If you really want to do it with escaping, look at the Escaping Queries. But it would be better to do it with binding (as my example above)